# Slow SQL Server linq query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, performance, linq

I have a query that uses three tables: `Orders` / `ItemsByCustomers` / `Customers` like this:

```
dim res = from o in Orders 
          where o.ItemsByCustomers.Customers.custCity = "Atlanta"
          select ...
```

Apparently, LINQ is querying the database once for each row in the `orders` table.

Is there a way of doing the same query better in LINQ without using an explicit SQL command with joins?

Comment: Is it LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for linq to sql, should be something like:

```
Dim result = From a In dbCtx.Orders
                             Join b In dbCtx.ItemsByCustomers On b.ItemId Equals a.ItemId
                             Join c In dbCtx.Customers On c.CusomterId Equals b.CusomterId
                             Where c.custCity = "Atlanta"
                             Select a
```

Comment: Using explicit "join" syntax will return all necessary data in one go? Will this behave differently from "where a.itemsByCustomers.Customers"?

Comment: it depends what you want to retrieve. if you want all of them, then you may select all out at the end with anonymous type (instead of Select a only): Select New With{.A = a, .B=B, .C = C} ' but it's not ideal as all the relationship might not be reserved. this differs from using a.ItemsByCustomers.Customers which will preserve all the relationship and the data is queried based on the relationship which will go through a lot of round trips